# How can i upload Nodejs Api on AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy my **nodejs** APIs on aws server.

I tried many ways like I created **EC2** instance and downloading the pem2 file to connect it to my github account.

Now  GitHub and EC2 are connected but when I try to do

```
npm start
```

it's not working  showing code errors but same code woking fine on local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to deploy a Node.js API on AWS, including using services like AWS Elastic Beanstalk, AWS Lambda, and EC2 instances. Choose the approach that best fits your project's requirements.
Make sure your Node.js application is ready for deployment. This includes setting up any necessary configuration files, dependencies, and ensuring that your application can be run on a production environment.
Elastic Beanstalk is a platform-as-a-service (PaaS) offering from AWS that makes it easy to deploy and manage applications. To deploy your Node.js API **using Elastic Beanstalk:**
Install the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) if you haven't already.
Package your application into a ZIP file, including your Node.js files, package.json, and any other relevant files.
Use the eb init command to initialize your Elastic Beanstalk environment.
Use the eb create command to create an environment and deploy your application.
**Deploying with AWS Lambda and API Gateway:**
AWS Lambda is a serverless computing service that allows you to run code without provisioning or managing servers. You can pair it with AWS API Gateway to create a fully serverless API.

Create a Lambda function for your API using the AWS Lambda console.
Set up an API Gateway that triggers your Lambda function.
Deploy your API using the API Gateway console.
Deploying with EC2 Instances:
If you prefer more control over the environment, you can deploy your Node.js API on EC2 instances.

Launch an EC2 instance with an appropriate Amazon Machine Image (AMI).
SSH into the instance and install Node.js, npm, and any other required dependencies.
Upload your application files to the instance, either manually or using tools like scp or Git.
Set up a process manager like pm2 to keep your Node.js application running.
Configure Security and Networking:
Regardless of the deployment approach, configure security groups, network settings, and other relevant security measures to protect your application.

**Monitor and Scale:**
Set up monitoring tools and alarms to keep track of your application's performance. Depending on your traffic, consider configuring auto-scaling to handle varying loads.

**Domain Name and HTTPS:**
If you have a custom domain, you can set it up using Amazon Route 53 or other DNS services. Additionally, consider setting up HTTPS using AWS Certificate Manager and configuring it on your load balancer or API Gateway.

Remember that each AWS service has its own nuances, and the specific steps may vary slightly. Always refer to the AWS documentation for the most up-to-date and detailed instructions for deploying your Node.js API on the chosen AWS service.

Comment: I created an EC2 instance and Uploaded the code there. After that, I install required files like nodejs, nginx, MongoDB, etc, and try to run the project using PM2 but not able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Set Up an AWS Account:**
   If you don't have an AWS account, sign up for one at https://aws.amazon.com/. You'll need a valid credit card to set up your account.
2. **Choose a Deployment Method:**
   There are several ways to deploy a Node.js API on AWS. One common approach is using Amazon EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud), which provides scalable virtual server instances. Alternatively, you can use AWS Lambda for a serverless deployment. Below, I'll outline how to deploy using both methods.

Deploying with Amazon EC2: An Amazon EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud) instance is a virtual server in the cloud where you can run your Node.js API. You can launch an EC2 instance through the AWS Management Console.

1. ***Launch an EC2 Instance***:

   - Go to the AWS Management Console.
   - Navigate to the EC2 dashboard.
   - Click on "Launch Instance."
   - Choose an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that suits your needs (typically a Linux AMI).
   - Configure instance details, including instance type, security groups, and key pairs.
2. ***Connect to Your EC2 Instance:***

   - Use SSH to connect to your instance using the key pair you created.You can use tools like `ssh` (command line) or software like PuTTY (Windows)
   - Once the instance is running, you can connect to it using SSH. You can use the ssh command from your terminal to connect to your instance using the key pair you specified during instance creation.

   ```
    ssh -i /path/to/your/key.pem ec2-user@your-instance-public-ip
   ```

   - Navigate to the directory where you want to deploy your API.
3. ***Upload Your Code:***

   - You can use `scp` or other methods to upload your code to the EC2 instance.
4. ***Install Node.js and Dependencies:***

   - Update the package manager (`sudo apt update` for Ubuntu) and install Node.js and npm.
   - Navigate to your project directory and run `npm install` to install the project dependencies.
5. ***Run Your Node.js Application:***

   - Use a process manager like `pm2` to run your Node.js app in the background.
   - Start your application using `pm2 start app.js` or the appropriate command for your application's entry point.

**Deploying with AWS Lambda:**

1. ***Create a Lambda Function:***

   - Go to the AWS Management Console.
   - Navigate to the Lambda dashboard.
   - Click on "Create function."
   - Choose "Author from scratch," and configure your function details.
   - Upload your code as a `.zip` file or from an S3 bucket.
2. ***Configure Trigger:***

   - Add an API Gateway trigger to your Lambda function. This will expose your API via an HTTP endpoint.
3. ***Set Up API Gateway:***

   - Configure the API Gateway to route incoming requests to your Lambda function.
4. ***Test Your API:***

   - Use the provided API Gateway endpoint to test your deployed API.

*Remember, the exact steps can vary based on your specific needs and preferences. Additionally, consider using a deployment script or a CI/CD pipeline for smoother deployments and updates.*